# C# Newtonsoft JArray. JSON cannot create empty array in empty array

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to create a JSON object with Newtonsoft. Everything looks fine but I can't create empty array in in empty array. I need the following output...

**My code:**

```
JObject rss = new JObject(
  new JProperty("query",
    new JObject(
      new JProperty("aoi",
        new JObject(
          new JProperty("type", "Polygon"),
            new JProperty("coordinates",
              new JArray(
                new JArray(
                  new JArray(
                    new JValue(-122.62664794921874),
                      new JValue(38.81403111409755)
                    ),
                    new JArray(
                      new JValue(-122.62664794921874),
                      new JValue(38.81403111409755)
                    )
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
```

**What I get:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "aoi": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [ -122.62664794921874, 38.81403111409755 ],
        [ -122.62664794921874, 39.07464374293249 ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**What I need:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "aoi": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [ -122.62664794921874, 38.81403111409755 ],
          [ -122.62664794921874, 39.07464374293249 ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about use standart .NET object and serialize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single JArray as a parameter to the JArray constructor is interpreted as content that should be copied to the new JArray. It works if you do like this:

```
 JObject rss = new JObject(
        new JProperty("query",
            new JObject(
                new JProperty("aoi",
                    new JObject(
                        new JProperty("type", "Polygon"),
                        new JProperty("coordinates",
                            new JArray(
                                new JArray(
                                    new JArray(
                                        new JValue(-122.62664794921874),
                                        new JValue(38.81403111409755)
                                        ),
                                    new JArray(
                                        new JValue(-122.62664794921874),
                                        new JValue(38.81403111409755)
                                        )
                                ) as Object
                        ))
                        ))
                ))
        );
```

That makes the constructor see it as something that should be inserted rather than copied.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect.

Comment: @Optimist, best way to say "Thank you" is to accept the answer if it solves your problem.